# Time stamp button.

Tags: feature-request, edits

**An Edit Button**

Pretty straight forward. A button that you can click on that will auto-insert **Edited at 1 Aug 2011 13:30** or something to that effect.

[image: Edit Bar]

Comment: ... there is an edit button. The history is included as well with time stamps. That's also an extremely vague title btw.

Comment: For feature requests, you should make sure to specify why you think the site will benefit from it.

Answer (score 10):

That won't be necessary since the site automatically puts in a timestamp for you underneath all the posts you've edited.

[image: edit timestamp 1]

Time stamps will even show the last user that submitted the edit:

[image: edit timestamp 2]

I'll even provide a real, live, working example right below this answer:

[image: edit timestamp 2]

Comment: Is that a hand-drawn semicircle, or a curly bracket?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: It's a freehand curly bracket. It was going to be a full freehand circle surrounding the actual timestamp but I haven't figured out how to make that work. :-P

Comment: @In silico The edit button was meant to be a convince thing, so instead of having to type Edit: they could click the button and the text would just show up. My mistake for not clarifying.

Comment: @johnthexiii: The point I was trying to get across is that you don't need to type "Edited ... " in your posts because the Stack Overflow engine does that for you below your posts. Therefore a button to insert the text is redundant.

Comment: Adding Edit: markers is for the most part unnecessary noise. The most important thing is the final state of your post, not how it got there. Anyone who's interested in that can look at the revision history. There are cases where edit markers make sense, but for the most part they should be avoided. – hammar, I have since been informed of that.